# Update UITableView Cell imageView by Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdk

Is it possible to update the cell imageView in an iOS UITableView by tag? I appreciate other methods are available but I would like to use tags if possible.

I set the image by:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dinner.png"];
```

And in another method I can get the cell by (Tags are always unique):

```
NSInteger the_tag = ((UIView*)sender).tag;
UITableViewCell *updateCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView viewWithTag:the_tag];
```

Is it possible to update the cell with this method? This does not work:

```
updateCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lunch.png"];
```

EDIT:

On reflection, the **tags are bad method to use**. You can use (Which will give you the row and the section if you have a sectioned table):

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Tapped Row %@", indexPath);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self->tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lunch.png"];
}
```

Comment: Why would you prefer to use tags? It's brittle, and in this case it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: I think you need to place [self.tableView beginUpdates]; before your code and [self.tableView endUpdates]; behind your code, to force TableView to update its content.

Comment: I agree, tags are a bad method! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];

   UIImageView *imageView = cell.imageView;//CustomCell you have imageView as @propertyVariable..
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you...

Answer (score 1):

try calling `[updateCell setNeedsLayout]` or `[updateCell.imageView setNeedsLayout]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately they cause "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error as before.

Comment: according to your log, it sounds like the viewWithTag returns directly the ImageView, not the cell

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. On reflection, I feel tags are a bad method to use. I have updated my original post with what I feel is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int tag = 2;//this is same at table cell row number.
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView viewWithTag:tag];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
```